# Javascript/PHP How to save slider value once form submitted?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with random filters and a slider that adjusts the width/height of items.
How can I save the slider value once the form is submitted so that when I go back to the slider, I see the value I left it on?

My attempt:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" name="slider_id" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['slider_id'])){ echo $_POST['slider_id']; }?>">
<div id="slider"></div>
```

The Javascript:

```
 $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
          value:$("input[name='slider_id']").val(), min: 80, max: 400, step: 10,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value-70 + "%" );
            $('.display').css('width', ui.value + 'px');
          }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val(  $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) + "%" );
      });
```

Right now it will show NaN after the form is submitted. All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here: `$("input[name='slider_id']").val()`
Debug it and you'll find that it's some form of "nn%", thus, a string.
`$.slider` requires that `value` be numeric.
You need to parse it somehow:

```
value: parseInt($("input[name='slider_id']").val().replace('%', ''), 10)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a hidden input to store the raw value and use that server-side?

Comment: that seemed to work! but how can I make the new value still effect the items width after the form is submitted? right now they just reset after the submit button is clicked

Comment: I was thinking of that but wasn't sure how to do it.. I tried <input type="hidden" name="slider_val" id="slider_amount">

Comment: Just call `$('.display').css('width', parsed_value_from_#amount + 'px');` before creating the slider.

Comment: What should I put for parsed_value_from_#amount? I mean, how do I get that value and put it there?

Comment: No, you need the numeric value, so use `parseInt($("input[name='slider_id']").val().replace('%', ''), 10)`

Comment: I tried doing var myValue = parseInt($("input[name='slider_id']").val().replace('%', ''), 10); then putting myValue after the 'width', and it didn't seem to work

Comment: Well then debug. I don't have access to your code so I can only guess as to what the problem could be. `alert(myValue)`, make sure it's not a CSS issue and so on.

Comment: the css is fine, it has simple 100% width so it adjusts with the slider. is the php code for the input correct? value="<?php if (isset($_POST['slider_id'])){ echo $_POST['slider_id']; }?>"

Comment: Yes, that looks fine.

Comment: i added else{echo '150';} as it was not getting any value before the form is submitted. still though, I can set the slider to a value and save the value, but after the form is submitted, there is no effect on the divs until i move the slider again

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that the problem is in php value set. 
Just modify the value of the input before calling the slider.

```
    $(function () {
     var newVal = $('input').val().replace("%","");
     $('input').val(newVal);
     $("#slider").slider({
         value: $("input[name='slider_id']").val(),
         min: 80,
         max: 400,
         step: 10,
         slide: function (event, ui) {
             $("#amount").val(ui.value - 70 + "%");
             $('.display').css('width', ui.value + 'px');
         }
     });
     $("#amount").val($("#slider").slider("value") + "%");     
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joeSaad/hZCDZ/#base

Comment: that removed the slider completely!

Comment: the code seems to be working on the front-side as per the jsfiddle. Could it be the php is not getting the right value. Can you check if the php is coming out right?

Comment: the only php is in the value="<?php if (isset($_POST['slider_id'])){ echo $_POST['slider_id']; }else{echo '150';}?>" of the input where for your jsfiddle example it says 90%. I want to be able to get that value displayed after the form is submitted. If i just set to 90% it won't show me the value once changed right?

Comment: No! the php is just the initial value, if it is present then it would be set to the initial value. if empty, I can see from your code that 80 will be the initial minimum value. http://jsfiddle.net/joeSaad/uD8jE/#base